# Use the Azure DevOps WorkItemTracking sendmail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to use the sendmail functionality of the Azure DevOps WorkItemTracking api; but get the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name ClientRecipients"

It's not a field in the API - so frankly I'm lost.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Response

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: clientRecipients","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Source code

```
    const sessionToken = await VSS.getAccessToken();
    const authToken = authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(sessionToken);
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1`,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            message: {
                body: 'Hello World',
                subject: 'My email',
                to: {
                    tfIds: ['my-profile-id']
                }
            },
            projectId: project
        }),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authToken);
        },
        success: (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        },
        error: (e) => {
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
```

(updated to include token code)

Comment: Have you tried to use the emailAddresses in the "to" recipients?

Comment: Yes - both without without the tfIds parameter. The error is the same

Comment: I also got this error, when used emailAdddresses, any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found through experimentation that the API requires the "cc" field to be present:

```
"message": {
    "body" : "Test Body",
    "cc" : {},
    "to" : {
        "tfsIds" : ["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"],
    },
    "replyTo" : {},
    "subject" : "Test Subject"
}
```